# neatupload runtime error "cant detect few class files "

Tags: .net, neatupload

I was getting this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] 
   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadStorage.CreateUploadStorageConfig() in D:\__projects\Brettle\NeatUpload\dotnet\src\Brettle.Web.NeatUpload\Brettle.Web.NeatUpload\UploadStorage.cs:55 
   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.FileControl.get_StorageConfig() in D:\__projects\Brettle\NeatUpload\dotnet\src\Brettle.Web.NeatUpload\Brettle.Web.NeatUpload\FileControl.cs:99 
   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.InputFile.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) in D:\__projects\Brettle\NeatUpload\dotnet\src\Brettle.Web.NeatUpload\Brettle.Web.NeatUpload\InputFile.cs:242 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +163 
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32 
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +51 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19 
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99 
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25 
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266
```

I think the dll reference i added from your class library doesnt contian these files

Adn Also I cant find your demo.aspx which was supposed to be in the folder neatupload.

Can you help me with this ASAP

I cant even debug the code

just throwing this runtime error straight away

Answer (score 0):

Salve!  I wrote a little guide about installing NeatUpload for .net just to get the demo to work.  There are some explanations there about download packages and where to find certain files.  Take a look:  [How to Install NeatUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391657/how-to-install-neatupload/10400485#10400485)

There is another post here about a NeatUpload error.  The solution may have some clues for you.  [How to Overcome this NeatUpload Object Reference Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402552/how-to-overcome-this-neatupload-object-reference-error/10442467#10442467)