# How to Overcome this NeatUpload Object Reference Error?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, neatupload

Having installed NeatUpload (http://neatupload.codeplex.com/), and put the demo onto my server (Windows Server 2008 and IIS7), when I select an object in the combobox for the "Progress Bar Location", and change it to "Inline", I get an unhandled exception, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.  I can change it to "none" and "popup" without issue.

Here is my installation guide: [How to Install NeatUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391657/how-to-install-neatupload/10400485#10400485)

Here is the stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadModule.get_PostBackID() +18
   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ProgressBar.get_LastPostBackIDQueryStringPortion() +9
   Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ProgressBar.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +687
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +107
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3393
```

What is missing?  I am able to view the "NeatUpload Console" okay, and can choose files for upload okay, and can change the "Submit button type" without issue.  Also, I never do get any progressbar.  The only thing I can think of is that my web-application runs in .net 2, and not .net 4 - if that be the problem, how do I fix it for the control without changing it for the web application (sharepoint 2010)?  Could I have some file out of place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!  Newbie problem.  Any additions that need to be made in the web.config need to be added to the web.config at the root of the web-application - it won't do to put any web.config files in the subfolders.  A web.config file can only go in the root of a web-application.  If we add a web-application in iis within the tree of another web-application, then we can add another web.config.  But putting a web.config in a subfolder does not make that directory into a web-application.  ...Learning the hard way....

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error as the question poster, but my fix was to switch the AppPool from Integrated to Classic pipeline.  I am using IIS7.

I also think that you can add:

```
<add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
```

To the `configuration/system.webServer/modules` part of your Web.config to allow it to work in  Integrated Pipeline Mode.

Comment: You can indeed add that web.config line! Have a very late upvote for saving my bacon on some legacy code problems :)